# How does one select/unselect all options in a select List using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am not yet familiar with jQuery, so it's been difficult to get the syntax correct for this.
I'm trying to select or unselect all the elements of a selectlist element, all at once, based on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

I found some help here at SO, but after a lot of looking and testing, need to ask the community...

In the if/else branch below, the else branch works correctly:

```
   if ($('input[name="select_markers"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $("#markerlist").prop('selected',true);
    } else {
        $('form select option').prop('selected',false);
    }
```

However, this affects all the select elements in the form, which I don't want. I only want to affect the element #markerlist, which I am attempting to do in the if branch -- but I cannot get this part to work.

I've seen many other examples that iterate over a select element, but I'd like to get this cleaner syntax to work, if I can.

TIA,
rixter

Comment: Did you try this?
 $('form select option') =>  $('#marketlist option')      Not sure I understood the problem.

Comment: Make a fiddle if you can.  I would like to see the HTML for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input[name="select_markers"]').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#markerlist').find('option').prop('selected','selected')
        }
        else {
            $('#markerlist').find('option').prop('selected',false)
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Fgh4S/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 $(".someClass option").attr("selected", "selected");
```