# how to unselect all selections

Tags: jquery

I asked this once before (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745253/how-does-one-select-unselect-all-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery?rq=1)), but I've become stuck again, and that code does not seem to work in another example.

The GUI now has two different picklists. stylabid and pjtlabid. If I click on one of them, I want any selected items in the other list to get cleared.

Here is the jquery code:

```
$('input[name="stylabid"]').change(
    function(){
      $('#pjtlabid').find('option').prop('selected',false)
    });
```

But this has no effect...does anyone see what's wrong here?

TIA,
rixter
PS -- Since some of you asked, here is the HTML code:

```
<div id=content-container2>
      <fieldset>
      <LEGEND><b>Select Study Sample</b></LEGEND>
    <p>
    <P CLASS=select_header>Study - Box - Well - Lab ID<br>
    <SELECT multiple size=20 NAME="stylabid" onchange=show_stylabid() onclick=clear_fetch() STYLE="width: 115px">
    <?php 
      $i=0;
      while ($i < $numstylabids) {
        $styarr = pg_fetch_row($stylabidresult);
        echo "<option value=$styarr[0]>$styarr[1]\n";
        $i++;           
      }
      ?>
    </select>
    </p>                
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

and the second select list:

```
<fieldset>
      <LEGEND><b>Select Project Sample</b></LEGEND>
    <p>
    <P CLASS=select_header>Project - Box - Well - Lab ID<br>
    <SELECT multiple size=20 NAME="pjtlabid" onchange=show_pjtlabid() onclick=clear_fetch() STYLE="width: 115px">
    <?php 
      $j=0;
      while ($j < $numpjtlabids) {
        $pjtarr = pg_fetch_row($pjtlabidresult);
        echo "<option value=$pjtarr[0]>$pjtarr[1]\n";
        $j++;           
      }
      ?>
    </select>
    </p>                
      </fieldset>
```

Comment: Can we see your markup?  Is there actually an element with `id=pjtlabid`?

Comment: The nature of a select list is that there is always something selected.  Are we talking multi-selects?

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2dmU/). The demo will change the value, no need to type...

Comment: Yes, multi-selects are possible; and, sorry, I did not understand the demo. But it was cool find out about jFiddle...

Comment: @rixter The idea was that when the value of a `<select>` is cleared it will simply reset to (*only*) the top value in the list (because something will always be 'selected' since the `<select>` always shows a value). If you watch the result panel in the lower right it starts at 3, then is reset to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The GUI now has two different picklists. stylabid and pjtlabid. If I click on one of them, I want any selected items in the other list to get cleared.

If by *picklist* you mean a `<select>` element, the problem is how you bind your change handler: a `<select>` is not an `<input>`. Instead, do:

```
$('select[name="stylabid"]').change( function() {
    $('#pjtlabid').find('option').prop('selected',false);
});
```

Also, be sure that you are using the [right selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/); `'#pjtlabid'` selects the element whose **ID** is *pjtlabid*, while `[name="stylabid"]` selects the element whose **name** is *stylabid*. The name and ID attributes are not the same.

Comment: Good to see you mate! `:)` +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer; it helps me to understand a bit better, but I've still not solved the problem...

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the selected attribute anything selected by the selector will be false. Try this:

```
$('select[name="stylabid"]').change(function(){
    $('#pjtlabid option').removeAttr('selected');
});
```

Comment: Why not man +1 to you as well `:)` not sure if removeattr is needed try adding `.prop` as well!

Comment: Could not get this to work either...I'm afraid my knowledge of jQuery syntax is quite weak...

Answer (score 0):

Like this man? http://jsfiddle.net/5XFrc/1/

Paste in your html and I will make specific demo, Please let me know if this helps, or I am happy to remove this post.

**Please note** on `change` you can use `this.checked` for the state and then use that state to update the property.

Hope it help the cause.

**code**

```
  $("#tableOne thead tr th:first input:checkbox").click(function() {
            var checkedStatus = this.checked;
            $("#tableOne tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each(function() {
                this.checked = checkedStatus;
            });
        });​
```